pm2 | как запустить приложение через poetry
надо выполнить всего 1 команду
poetry run python main -m
я уже перепробовал все комбинации разбиения команды на составные части и передачи в interpreter, script, args, node_args и т д
как это сделать?

Добавьте описание что пробовали в как результат. Кстати команда с ошибкой

Обычно все-таки сначала ключ -m идет, потом название модуля: python -m main. Ну и poetry run слева добавить.
